# Secure licensing system for iOS app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, security, encryption, ssl

A few similar questions have been asked before on SO, but I've yet to find one that pinpoints exactly what I'm trying to do.

I have an iOS app that I'm trying to build a reasonably secure licensing system for.

There will be a (PHP-based) central server with a front-end where people can buy licenses to use the software, and a back-end database which stores all the licensing information.

From the iOS app, users will be able to input a license key which then gets sent to the server, checked against the database, and the server will then respond with information pertaining to that license (e.g. expiry date) -- or will respond with an "authentication failed" message if no such license exists.

The question is how best to implement this, and what technologies should be deployed in order to make this work.

My first instinct would be to do public-key RSA encryption so that the server can sign all the license keys and the app can verify them. But is this overkill?

Would using SSL at the socket layer be sufficient to ensure that the license key is legitimate? (or could malicious users create spoof DNS records and pretend to be my license server and always send valid licenses?)

I'm trying to find a fairly neat and simple solution which also plays nicely between Objective-C/iOS and PHP.

Comment: Depending on your App type, you might want to check iOS's Developer Guidelines. That might not fly with them. Apple would prefer that you use In-App purchases so they get their 30% cut.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, it's fine to have your own external licensing server as long as you don't link to it from within the app. There are plenty of B2B apps which function like this already.

Comment: Specifically: (11.14)
Apps can read or play approved content (specifically magazines, newspapers, books, audio, music, and video) that is subscribed to or purchased outside of the app, as long as there is no button or external link in the app to purchase the approved content. Apple will not receive any portion of the revenues for approved content that is subscribed to or purchased outside of the app. -- So this is definitely allowed, but thanks for your concern :)

Comment: @jon: 11.14 only applies to "content" within the app ("specifically magazines, newspapers, books, audio, music, and video"). You can't lock out the whole application for unlicensed users; that's forbidden by guidelines 11.1, 11.2, 11.12, and possibly 11.9.

Comment: @duskwugg 11.2 is irrelevant to me as it specifically refers only to purchases made within the app. 11.12 also doesn't apply as I'm not using 11.12. With regard to 11.1 and 11.9, it is fairly ambiguous what it means, and either way Apple seem to be taking a blind eye to this as there are thousands of apps in the App Store that are free and rely on their own licensing system, often with time expiry. Examples: Cisco AnyConnect, TomTom WEBFLEET, Teletrac Fleet Director, Oracle CRM iSales,LoveFilm, heck, even Dropbox can be subscribed to outside of the app -- seemingly in violation of 11.1 & 11.9.

Comment: Sorry, when I say "I'm not using 11.12, I meant to say I'm not using IAP".

Comment: What solution did you got with for this in the end?